# Enable Windows command line history

Tags: windows, shell, windows-7, command-line

I understand that the Windows Command Line tool does not store the input history issued by the user. Is there a way to automatically enable this, to allow post-mortem examination of the commands issued?

Otherwise, is there an alternative to investigate what commands a particular system admin has performed in command line?

The applicable OS are Windows 7, and all versions of Windows Servers

Answer (score 2):

I believe by default windows cmd doesn't support this. 
So the direct answer to your question is that its just impossible.

However you can achive the effect you're asking for by using PowerShell.
[Look here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/01/perserving-command-history-across-sessions.aspx)
Disclamer, I didn't use it by myself :)

Answer (score 1):

press F7 while on command prompt

Comment: This is helpful thank you. You wouldn't happen to know if there is a way to increase history beyond 10 items would you?